# Дискорд бот на Python при отправке любой команды выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

При запуске дискорд бота на python3 и отправки любой команды (например !help) в консоли наблюдаю следующую ошибку:[image: Скриншот]

Comment: То что написано в ошибке: у метода change_presence нет именованного (keyword) аргумента game. Учитесь читать и хотя бы пытаться понимать текст ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно обьявили статус бота.Бот имеет по умолчанию статус Online
но если вы хотите имеено например играет или тд то можете поискать в документаций упоминание.Вот вам пример с официального сайта документаций. [Документация](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#general)

```py
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='my game'))

# or, for watching:
activity = discord.Activity(name='my activity', type=discord.ActivityType.watching)
await client.change_presence(activity=activity)
```